# MySQL - Update table when row gets selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM restaurants WHERE city='Kalmar' LIMIT 100
```

This is working as it should, but now I want to extend some functionality to it.
I want to keep count of how many times per day the rows has been selected.

Let's say we managed to select 5 restaurants from the query, I want to do something like this for each one of them:

```
INSERT INTO statistics (date, restaurant_id, number_of_selects) VALUES('{$current_date}', (The restaurants ID), 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number_of_selects = number_of_selects + 1"
```

What this code does is to increase restaurants number of selects inside the statistics-table. If the row doesn't exist (meaning, it's the first select) it will create the row.

And now to the problem!
What I could do is to loop all the results in PHP and use the second query. However, this is a performance killer. I'm looking for a way to use both these querys at the same  time to get the best performance possible.

*Edit:
I want to keep the data I select (In this case the name of the restaurants).*

Thanks in advance,
Tompa

Comment: You either loop all of them, otherwise you can give an array to the insert maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the inserts at once.

You'll want a multi-column unique key on statistics(date, restaurant_id) for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to do its trick.

```
INSERT INTO statistics (date, restaurant_id, number_of_selects)
SELECT '{$current_date}', restaurant_id, 1
FROM restaurants WHERE city='Kalmar' LIMIT 100
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number_of_selects = number_of_selects + 1
```

The `LIMIT 100` seems fishy at this point though. Maybe leave it out? Also, maybe use MySQL's `DATE(NOW())` instead of `{$current_date}`.

Comment: He need however to launch two query (one for insert and one for fetch the select data)

Comment: @MarcoMura, true if he needs those results, but it's not stated in the question. I hope that part's obvious, anyway. :) I improved my answer to indicate that I'm only including the update solution, not the select.

Comment: Can he even use an insert but with an array? He can give an Array to the procedure and the the insert will insert them? cannot this improve performance?

Comment: @MarcoMura, yes, assuming the `SELECT` is expensive and he's actually wanting the results from the `SELECT`. Consider demonstrating that in an answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest inserting the result first into a temporary table. Then use this table to update the statistics table, before returning the results to php. This will remove the need for a cursor / loop to iterate over the result set (which is what would kill your performance)

So something like:

```
--Get the restaurants
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTable AS
    (SELECT id, name
    FROM restaurants
    WHERE city='Kalmar'
    LIMIT 100
    )

--Update the statistics
INSERT INTO statistics (date, restaurant_id, number_of_selects)
SELECT DATE(), id
FROM tempTable
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number_of_selects = number_of_selects + 1

--Return data to PHP
SELECT name from tempTable
```

I havent checked the syntax etc, but I would expect something like that to work

Comment: If you do create a Cursor on Stored Procedure (On db) that will improve performance.

Comment: Creating a cursor, either in a sproc or elsewhere, is a bad idea if another option is available. Cursors work against the Set logic of SQL, thus degrading performance

Comment: I do not know if that is true. That said, if cursors are so bad, why do not use Insert Select or an insert (subquery) ?

Comment: I do use an Insert Select in my answer, no where in my answer did I say to use a cursor... And Yes cursors are very bad for performance (http://www.mssqlcity.com/Tips/tipCursor.htm).